# Read data from file in c++

Tags: c++

I have a file like this:

Linear eqation parameters: `a b`

> 2 4

Circle coord and radius:

> 1 1 2

Heat conduction

Unit ms

> 23

I want to read numbers into variables, e.g. `A=2 b=4 x=1 y=1 r=2 u=23`

Do I have to use `getline` for each line, and then extract numbers from string?

Comment: Yes, you would use `getline`, then insert the line into a stringstream and extract the integers from the stringstream to the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can, you can use getline to store into a string variable, then extract the number using `sscanf`.

For example,

```
sscanf(data, "%i %i %i", &x, &y, &r);
```

You can use `float` or `double` datatype as well, depending on your needs.

Comment: But after using sscanf，it cannot jump to next line automatically

Comment: `sscanf` is reading from a string variable, so yes it does not jump to the next line. You can read the next line using the `getline`, so inside your `while` loop, you will call `getline`, and then `sscanf`.

Comment: Or I can use fstream to input: fstream file; file>>a>>b; then followed by "getline" to jump to next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix getline and reading from 'cin'. Say, read one line, then read two integers by 'cin' and so on

Answer (score 0):

Do u can store data in file like "2 4 1 1 2 23" ? Then it will be much easier. just read the entire line, and fill the value by one.